# vectores en java

Tags: java

quiero que me compare una letra con el vector respuesta por cada estudiante que ingrese como hago para que me tome  la letra y me la compare

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] respuestas = {'B','C','A','D','A','E','A','E','B','D'};
    char [] estudiantes = new char[1];

    for(int i=0;i<=estudiantes.length;i++){

        System.out.println("ingrese respuesta");
        estudiantes[i]=in.next().charAt(0);
         if(estudiantes[i]==(respuestas[0])){
        System.out.println(" respuesta");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice lo que estabas pidiendo. Solo que en vez de usar el ciclo `FOR`, use `WHILE` para una busqueda.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] respuestas = {'B','C','A','D','A','E','A','E','B','D'};
    char [] estudiantes = new char[1];
    int i = 0;


    System.out.println("ingrese respuesta en MAYUSCULAS");
    estudiantes[0] = in.next().charAt(0);

    while(respuestas[i] != estudiantes[0] && i < respuestas.length - 1 ){
        i++;
    }

     if(i < respuestas.length -1){
         System.out.println("respuesta correcta");
     }else{
         System.out.println("respuesta incorrecta");
     }
```